# Mathematical expression for process id as function of grid size, number of processes and line id

Tags: c, math, mpi

i'm writting a program with some group mates that simulates the positions of animals in a NxN cells world. We've done it as a serial program and now i'm changing it to distributed, using OpenMPI. We decided to distribute world lines evenly by processes.

Example: in a 8x8 world (N=8), with 3 processes (p=3):

```
pid=0 handles lines 0, 1 and 2;
pid=1 handles lines 3, 4 and 5;
pid=2 handles lines 6 and 7.
```

What I need is a mathematical expression (not a C function!) that gives me pid as a function of N (number of lines in the world), p (number of processes) and i (line index) [pid = f(N, p, i)]

```
Using previous example:
f(8, 3, 0) = 0;
f(8, 3, 1) = 0;
f(8, 3, 2) = 0;
f(8, 3, 3) = 1;
f(8, 3, 4) = 1;
f(8, 3, 5) = 1;
f(8, 3, 6) = 2;
f(8, 3, 7) = 2;
```

I do not want a function because, if I have a 1000000x1000000 world, with aproximately 1000000^2 animals, that function would be called once per animal. I think a "simple" mathematical expression is faster, but I'm having trouble to deduce it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer was on the course notes...

> pid = max( floor(i/ceiling(N/p)), floor((i-(N%p))/floor(N/p)) );

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You mean that if p=3, then s (size) = N / p, and for any i in N:

```
pid = roundUp(i/N*s)
```

is that it?

Comment: Thansk, but that's not correct.
Firstly, size is not only N/p. In the example i've shown N/p = 2 and there are 2 processes with 3 lines each.

Comment: Size is the roundUp of N/p, in this case 3, on your example it's the size {3,3,2}

Comment: (continuing first comment) Secondly, `roundUp(i/N)` is always 1, since i is in [0; N-1]

Comment: @Dmitri, yes, you're right. I've deleted it because I realised it was wrong. Thanks

Comment: With size = roundUp(N/p) i see everything working as intended, is it really not working in some way?

Comment: @fernando.reyes, for f(8,3,i), your expression gives 3 for any i

Comment: I just saw the error, the roundUp is on the whole operation, the thing is roundingUp after multiplying, does it work now?

Comment: @fernando.reyes, then it is just roundUp(i/p). f(8,3,1) would be 1 and it should be 0.

I guess i'll have to write a function to calculate it...

Comment: Ok, the function is calculation indexes from 1..N, my bad